# How to gray out "// comment" lines in Emacs?

Tags: regex, emacs

Regular expression trouble in Emacs: how do I highlight all lines that begin with "//"?

I would like to gray out my comments in text mode but the following snippet doesn't seem to work:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
(lambda()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
  '(("^//.+"
     1 font-lock-comment-face prepend)))))
```

'Re-builder' indicated that this kind of expression *should* do the trick. What's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it yourself. That way, other users with the same problem will find your question and see that it has been answered.

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip. I figured out the solution right after posting and -- out of impatience -- wanted to post it right away. But I wasn't allowed to, and hence the editing. Sorry, won't happen again.

Comment: @mart: That's OK. It's all sorted beautifully now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. `"^\\(//.*\\)$"` does the job.

Sorry for possible "spam". I did google for almost two hours beforehand; regular expressions just seem to be way above my head.

Comment: +1: FYI, ihe issue here is that Emacs's variation on RE syntax uses `\(` and `\)` for capturing parentheses (many other variants use `(` and `)`, but not here). Those literal backslashes have to be doubled up in a string in program code.

Comment: Yes, thanks for explaining; that's what I (finally) realized, too.

Answer (score 3):

Since the regular expression matches everything that the highlighting is to be applied to, there's an alternate method:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
(lambda()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
  '(("^//.+"
     0 font-lock-comment-face prepend)))))
```

The `0` says to use the whole match (as opposed to `1` for the first subpattern, etc.)

---

Mind you, if you're writing an emacs mode then the way they do this is by defining a suitable syntax table that declares this sort of thing to be a comment and then arranging for the highlighter to use the comment face for comments. (I think it does that by default if turned on at all.) The [tutorial on writing major modes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeTutorial) covers full C++-style comments and says something about how to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not writing a mode, I just needed to tweak the Markdown mode a bit. I mostly write text (not code), and "//" is my preferred syntax for comments. Now that it's grayed out nicely, that's all I currently need. However, I'll definitely look into writing modes myself some day.

Comment: @mart: OK, I couldn't tell for sure and so I mentioned it. :-)